# SQL adding select field changes results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to reconcile these two queries

```
SELECT DISTINCT(customer_id), date FROM questions
WHERE question_id = 283 OR
question_id = 282
```

returns 139 rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT(customer_id) FROM questions
WHERE question_id = 283 OR
question_id = 282
```

returns 138 rows, (not selecting date)

Table looks like this

```
quesiton_id           date
--------------------------------
288                 1/1/2010
288                 1/1/1999
283                 1/1/2006
283                 1/1/2007
283                 null
```

How is this type of behavior possible?

Comment: `DISTINCT` only checks the _entire_ row for being distinct (not a specific column).  So `283 1/1/2006` is distinct from `283 1/1/2007`.  I don't know how it handles null though.

Comment: If it checks the entire row, then why do we pass in one column to Distinct?

Comment: You can `Select distinct col1, col2, col3 from table` the ()'s are being ignored which will return unique rows.  Or you can `select count(Distinct col1), col2 from table group by col2` which will give you a count of unique values in col1 for each group in col2.  Distinct isn't a function as you're alluding to requiring ()'s.   It's a statement or clause, not a function...

Comment: Check out [this article](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx) on using distinct and null (about half way down)

Comment: Also, Your output of 2nd query doesn't make sense... Date wasn't in the select, nor was question_id for that matter.... so how could date be in the output.  If you run `select count(Distinct customer_ID) from questions` what do you get?  Should be a count of all different questions who answered questions regardless if they answered multiple questions or the same question on different dates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(customer_id), date
FROM  . . .
```

You are only confusing yourself.  You are treating `DISTINCT` as if it were a function.  It isn't.  Is is better to think of it as an option on the `SELECT` keyword.  Regardless of the parentheses that you use, this is interpreted as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, date
FROM  . . .
```

If you are learning SQL, it is very rare that you really need the `DISTINCT` keyword.  You can write the query using `GROUP BY` instead -- and the query plans are typically identical.  So, I would advise you to write the query as:

```
SELECT customer_id, date
FROM questions
WHERE question_id IN (282, 283)
GROUP BY customer_id, date ;
```